# Долгое выполнение запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

хочу узнать нормально ли это, что такой, на мой взгляд долгий запрос выполняется долго. В каждой таблице около 2 миллионов записей

```
select count(distinct user_id), count(distinct id) from product.user_session_end left join product.users on user_session_end.user_id = users.id;
```

Comment: Запрос выполняется более 15 минут и не выполнился

Comment: Хотя бы примерно опиши характеристики того на чем пытался выполнять.

Comment: Конечно нормально. Вы каждую строку в двух миллионах пытаетесь связать с другой строкой из двух миллионов. Не понимаю суть запроса. Если нужно просто количество строк в таблицах, то сделайте двумя запросами и выведите в один результат используя `union`. Иначе зачем такой запрос?

Comment: Отдельно посчитайте количество в подзапросах, и только потом связывайте. Или последуйте совету @MaxDown. Сейчас сервер должен объединить 4 триллиона записей, а потом отсортировать значения в указанных полях для подсчёта уникальных - я думаю, что сервер и за сутки не справится...

Comment: @Akina не получится ведь в отдельных подзапросах просто посчитать. В юзерах может быть больше записей, чем в сессиях (получится всего пользователей, и всего пользователей  у которых есть сессия, разные вещи). и 4трлн не будет, он же не декартово произведение строит, а по условию сливает

Comment: @teran Да я вообще не знаю, из какой таблицы какое поле берётся... хоть бы структуры показал, что ли. И вообще - подобный запрос наводит на мысль, что есть сессии от несуществующих юзеров.

Comment: @Akina оба поля привязаны к таблицам в условиях джойна. Если бы они дублировались в таблицах, то была бы ошибка про неопределенность именования. Возможно про inner автор не знает. Хотя с другой стороны, если в условии джойна - равенство полей, то и каунт дистинкт будет одинаковым. Разве что и правда есть сессии без юзера и distinct id ,будет меньше